# .toString doesn't work on array values? (Jscript)

Tags: arrays, tostring, jscript, wsh

I'm trying to convert an array value that contains a path to a string.  I want to do this because I want to use the regex `.replace` method to get rid of the large part of the path and leave just the file and its containing folder.  I thought the path in the array was a string but `.replace` won't work on it, though it works fine converting `555` to `666`.

The program prints out arrayValue fine but when I put the `.toString()` on it it throws an error (which I can't read because the console immediately closes and I don't know how to make it pause for an exception).

```
for (i=0; i < dirArrays.length; i++) {
        fileIsThere = false;
        for (k=0; k < dirArrays[i].length; k++) {
            arrayValue = dirArrays[i][k];
            x = 555
            WScript.Echo('dirArrays[' + i + '][' + k + '] = ' + x.toString() + ' ' + x.toString().replace(/5/g, '6') + ' ' + arrayValue.toString() )
            if ( /replacedData.txt$/.test(dirArrays[i][k]) ) {
                fileIsThere = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!fileIsThere) {
        throw 'replacedData.txt missing from \mls_num_' + i
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

General rule: Use [Array.slice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkcsy6fe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to get parts of an array. Applied to your problem: Use Array.slice(.length - n, .length) to get the 'tail' of a path:

```
/* I want ... to get rid of the large part of the path and leave just
   the file and its containing folder
*/

var sPath = WScript.ScriptFullName;
WScript.Echo(0, sPath);
var aPath = sPath.split(/\\/);
WScript.Echo(1, aPath);
var aTail = aPath.slice(aPath.length - 2, aPath.length);
WScript.Echo(2, aTail.join("\\"));
```

output:

```
cscript 25877076.js
0 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\25301708\jscript\25877076.js
1 E:,trials,SoTrials,answers,25301708,jscript,25877076.js
2 jscript\25877076.js
```

(which can be studied at leisure, if you execute your scripts via cscript.exe in a console/'DOS box')

Comment: This is a good answer but I figured out why `.toString()` wouldn't work: the element in the array was a WSH `File` object.  So I used the `Name` property and the regexp works fine on it.